# При парсинге не получает страницу полностью

Tags: php, парсер

Хочу запарсить сайт, но он парсится не полностью. И я выяснил что беда с не курлом и вообще с моим кодом, а в самом сайте. Почему-то даже когда просматриваешь код этого сайта через ctrl+u, в нем не отображается некоторая информация. Почему? Как это?)

Comment: Может там контент подгружается откуда-либо, например тем же `AJAX`?

Comment: JS просто скорее всего

Comment: понятно, то есть запарсить страницу полностью не получится?

Comment: @МаксСоколов, в некоторых случаях это возможно, почитай про `phantomjs`